# GitLab does not provide sub domain for their pages service?

Tags: github, gitlab

I wanted to set up a page at GitLab. I thought it'll be something similar like GitHub's, where they provide you a sub domain under the GitHub domain. However, as I'm reading the documentation and checking the settings page of the project, I've started to realise I need to have my own domain registration, and GitLab "just" sort of provides a hosting service for that domain.

My question is: am I seeing this right, or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitLab pages will be hosted on `<username>.gitlab.io`

-> No, you don't need to provide anything yourself.

Comment: It looks like you were right. Now GitLab has set up a page which explains every step required to create a site: [link](https://pages.gitlab.io/). It looks like my major issue was that I didn't edited the forked test site to trigger the runner.